# appending timestamp to tail -f results

Tags: tail, bash-scripting

I would like to have a timestamp printed in front of every line that comes out of a "tail -f outputfile", so that I know when is each line printed in. Something like:

```
[...]
20110617_070222:results printed here
20110617_070312:results printed here
20110617_070412:results printed here
20110617_070513:results printed here
[...]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that you aren't getting quite what you asked for.  The answers you've received are based upon the assumption that you don't mind the timestamp errors introduced by the fact that these are the times that `tail` writes to its standard output, _not_ the times that the lines were written to the original file in the first place.  You may well not mind, but be aware of this assumption derived from your question as it is written.

Comment: Duplicate question, with good answers: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26728/52959

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It probably doesn't get any shorter than this:

```
tail -f outputfile | xargs -IL date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S:L"
```

Note that I used the timestamp format suggested by your question, but you're free to use anything supported by the `date` command (the format syntax is supported by standard BSD and GNU date).

Comment: Note that `xargs` ignores empty lines. For my usecase that's fine but your milage may vary.

Comment: This will break if xargs encounters unmatched quote `"` in the line.

Comment: I see. Maybe `tail -f outputfile | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0IL date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S:L"` is better in this case? Also works with empty lines then.

Comment: Wouldn't this invoke `date` on each and every output line?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen That's right. But a few `date` invocations per second shouldn't be a problem on any system. Otherwise you probably should resort to a script or a compiled program. Or if you want to keep it pure bash you can restrict yourself to builtins, e.g.: `tail -f outputfile | while read line; do printf "%(%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)T:%s\n" "$EPOCHSECONDS" "$line"; done`; I didn't do any performance measurements here though. (But if you really need subsecond precision, just prefixing `$EPOCHREALTIME` makes more sense.)

Comment: @DavidOngaro It is not necessarily a bad thing, but important to know when you are deciding upon which solution is best for you.

Answer (score 6):

Write a simple script to do that.  Here's an example in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while(<>) {
    print localtime . ": $_";
}
```

To use the script, simply pipe your tail output through it:

```
tail -f outputfile | ./prepend_timestamp.pl
```

You could also do it inline:

```
tail -f outputfile | perl -pe '$_ = localtime.": $_"'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would normally do this with perl as answered by others, but it was unavailable at the rather trimmed down Linux machine where I needed it, but the busybox awk applet was!

```
tail -f some_file  | awk -e '{ print strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S",systime()) "\t" $0}'
```

As always the timestamp is for when the line was printed, not when it was written originally.

Answer (score 0):

With **awk**:

```
tail -f infile | awk '{"date \"+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S\"" | getline now} {close("date")} {print now ": " $0}'
```

Comment: This prints the same time for all lines in my case, even if they appear 10 seconds appart.

Comment: This prints the same time code at the front of every time, forever.